# How do I save an image from an API response in Hive?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-hive

JSON data:

```json
{
    "id":"1",
    "class_id":"2",
    "name":"bebeneo 204",
    "price":"16",
    "barcode":"72900000000",
    "item_img":"file/db_1p6.gif"
},
```

I receive through the API the name of the image (the `item_img` field). To be able to display the image, a server name must be placed before its name (EX: https://www.imageserver.com/file/db_1p6.gif). I want to save this image in Hive database.

Answer (score 1):

```
var decodedJson = json.decode(jsonStringHere);

var box = Hive.box('myBox');

box.put('imageUrl', 'https://www.imageserver.com/${decodedJson['item_img']}');
```

And to get it back

```dart
var imageUrl = box.get('imageUrl');

print('This is the image url: $imageUrl');
```